# How to identify system shut down or reboot events in exit handler?

Tags: c#, windows, process, .net-4.5, exit-handler

I have the following code to identify whether a process has exited or not. When it exits I am creating a notification in my application.

```
Process[] processes = RunningInstancesByName("MyService");

while (processes.Length <= 0)
{
  //Thread.Sleep(100);
  processes = RunningInstancesByName(name);
  }
  Process process = processes[0];

  process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
  process.Exited += this.Installer_Process_Exited;
  AddExitEvents(name, eventHandler);

  return process;
}
```

How do I identify whether this exit was triggered by a Windows shutdown or restart? Because if it is so, I should not create a notification through my application? Is there a way to identify whether this process exited because of such shut down or restart events? Please advice.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionended.aspx)  helps

Comment: There is no generic way to determine why a process exited.  If it is your own process, you could have it set a specific exit code if it is doing so in response to a system shutdown.  Otherwise, I think all you can do is to listen for a shutdown event yourself, and assume that processes that exit after that point are doing so because of the shutdown.  (You might also need to ignore process exits that occur shortly *before* you receive a shutdown notification.)